# How can I open a file in Perl using a wildcard in the directory name?

Tags: perl

I need to open a file called `OrthologousGroups.txt` from a directory that is named based on the date of when it is created. e.g. `./Results_2016-2-7`

Is there a way to use a wildcard in the path name to the file I need to access?

I tried the following

```
open(FILE, "./Results*/OrthologousGroups.txt");
```

but I get an error

> readline() on closed filehandle

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `glob` to get a list of filenames matching the glob pattern:

```
my @files = glob "./Results*/OrthologousGroups.txt";

if (@files != 1) {
    # decide what to do here if there are no matching files,
    # or multiple matching files
}

open my $fh, $files[0] or die "$! opening $files[0]";

# do stuff with $fh
```

As a general note, you should *check whether open succeeded*, instead of simply assuming it did, then you won't get "readline on closed filehandle" errors when you didn't actually open a file in the first place.

Comment: The OP doesn't say, but I think this is likely to be a question for Windows, in which case `use File::Glob ':bsd_glob'` is important to handle spaces in file paths