# Perl open file from command line with wildcard

Tags: perl, command-line, wildcard

I am executing my script this way:

```
./script.pl -f files*
```

I looked at some other threads (like [How can I open a file in Perl using a wildcard in the directory name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35471597/how-can-i-open-a-file-in-perl-using-a-wildcard-in-the-directory-name))

If i hard code the file name like it is written in this thread I get my desired result. If I take it from the command line it does not.

My options subroutine should save all the files I get this way in an array.

```
my @file;
sub Options{
  my $i=0;
  foreach my $opt (@ARGV){
    switch ($opt){
      case "-f" {
        $i++;

        ### This part does not work:
        @file= glob $ARGV[$i];
        print Dumper("$ARGV[$i]");   #$VAR1 = 'files'; 
        print Dumper(@file);   #$VAR1 = 'files'; 
      }
    }
    $i++;
  }
}
```

It seems the execution is interpreted in advance and the wildcard (*) is dropped in the process.

Desired result: All files beginning with **files** are saved in an array, after execution from the command line.

I hope you get my problem. If not feel free to ask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first I'd suggest using a module to do args on command line:
[Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) for example.

But otherwise your problem is simpler - your *shell* is expanding the 'file*' before perl gets it. (shell `glob` is getting there first).

If you do this with:

```
-f 'file*'
```

then it'll work properly. You should be able to see this - for example - if you just:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@ARGV;
```

I expect you'll see a much longer list than you thought.

However, I'd also point out - perl has a really nice feature you may be able to use (depending what you're doing with your files).

You can use `<>`, which automatically opens and reads all files specified on command line (in order).

Comment: lol, that was quite simple. But is there a way to do this without " or ' 
So one can auto complete the filenames with tab?

Comment: Yes - the problem is that in this case, the shell expands the pattern. Don't  give it a 'shell pattern' (E.g. if you tab complete) and it'll be fine.

Comment: meh ok. Thank you though =)

Answer (score 0):

Since your shell is already expanding the glob `files*` into a list of filenames, that's what the Perl program gets.

```
$ perl -E 'say @ARGV' files*
files1files2files3
```

There's no need to do that in Perl, if your shell can do it for you. If all you want is the filenames in an array, you already have `@ARGV` which contains those.

Comment: well, I need to do some stuff with these files and I need to let the user have options like -f, -h, etc.

Comment: Then you should use a module for processing the command line args like [Sobrique said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39391405/1331451), e.g. Getopt::Long. You can still use a list of filenames after that.

Comment: well, though I appreciate the advice, my question was not about how I check for options, but how I get the files from the command line.